# Set value for DP of type enum from Style is crashing the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I created custom lookless control that define a `DependencyProperty` of type `enum` and has a `ToggleButton` that should set this property via `Trigger` on `IsChecked` state. Somehow when I define `Setter` like this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger SourceName="ToggleButton" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ConnectionMode" Value="{x:Static Controls:ConnectionMode.Mode1}" />
  </Trigger>
  ...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

then the Visual Studio 2013 designer immediately fails with error:

`ArgumentException: 'Mode1' is not a valid value for the 'MyProject.Controls.CustomControl1.ConnectionMode' property on a Setter.

> at System.Windows.Setter.Seal()
>      at System.Windows.SetterBaseCollection.Seal()
>      at System.Windows.TriggerBase.ProcessSettersCollection(SetterBaseCollection setters)
>      at System.Windows.Trigger.Seal()
>      at System.Windows.TriggerCollection.Seal()
>      at System.Windows.StyleHelper.SealTemplate(FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, Boolean& isSealed, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, TriggerCollection triggers, ResourceDictionary resources, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalStructList`1& triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalStructList`1& containerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& resourceDependents, ItemStructList`1& eventDependents, HybridDictionary& triggerActions, HybridDictionary& dataTriggerRecordFromBinding, Boolean& hasInstanceValues, EventHandlersStore& eventHandlersStore)
>      at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Seal()

The `DependencyProperty` defined as:

```
namespace MyProject.Controls
{

    using ...

    public enum ConnectionMode
    {
       Mode1,
       Mode2,
    }

    public class CustomControl1 : ContentControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectionModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ConnectionMode", typeof(ConnectionMode), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(ConnectionMode), OnCustomConnectionModeChanged));
```

So my question is: How do I set the DP of type enum from `Trigger` and still see the control in 'design mode' in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property `ConnectionMode` is defined at `CustomControl1` so it cannot be set from ControlTemplate. Property can be set from CusotmControl1 Style though but not from control template.

Something like this will work:

```
<Controls:CustomControl1.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:CustomControl1}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ConnectionMode" 
                        Value="{x:Static Controls:ConnectionMode.Mode1}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Controls:CustomControl1.Style>
```

Comment: I thought that if I defined my `ControlTemplate` as
`<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomControl1Template" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:CustomControl1}">` so I have access to DP inside... Why not ? I mean - I defined _specific_ type of this `ControlTemplate`

Comment: Definitely you can do it from code behind by accessing parent control and setting it. But however, XAML have restrictions that you can bind (only get) to `TemplatedParent` property but cannot set the property on `TemplatedParent`.